# My code is unable to read the "function(this)" and is passing in the search paramaters instead

Tags: javascript, html, json, flask

Context of code:
So I am trying to paginate using the JSON values I receive from a function that I implemented, but I was unable to figure out how to paginate with only JSON values. And now I am trying to just make a prev and next button to get the appropriate results and render that page as a makeshift solution

Problem:
for some reason when I go to the url `/result?limit=2&offset=0`, I recieve this error in the HTML, where when I click the button expand(which is supposed to lead to the JS function myFunction(z)) it sends in `/result?limit=2&offset=0` instead of the tag where the button is located. Any help on the issue would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Project Details</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css'>
        <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>       
        <table id='my-table' class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> 
            <thead>
                <tr>            
                    <th>Project</th>
                    <th>Main Task</th>
                    <th>Sub Task</th>
                    <th>Start Date</th>
                    <th>Target Date</th>
                    <th>Actual Start Date</th>
                    <th>Actual Target Date</th>
                    <th>Estimate</th>
                    <th>Actual Hours Hours</th>
                    <th>Approved Hours</th>
                    <th>Overall Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {%- for val in details -%}
                <tr>
                    {%- set count = loop.index -1 -%}
                    <td><button id='{{count}}' onclick='myFunction(this)'>Expand</button>{{val['name']}}</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>{{val['start_date']}}</td>
                    <td>{{val['target_date']}}</td>
                    <td>{{val['timesheet_details']['actual_start_date']}}</td>
                    <td>{{val['timesheet_details']['actual_target_date']}}</td>
                    <td>{{val['estimate']}}</td>
                    <td>{{val['timesheet_details']['actual_hours']}}</td>
                    <td>{{val['timesheet_details']['approved_hours']}}</td>
                    <td>{{val['status']}}</td>
                </tr>
            {%- endfor -%}
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <script>
            function myFunction(z){
                console.log(z)
            }
            $(document).ready( function () {
                $('#my-Table').DataTable();
            } );
        </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

FLASK:

```
import flask
from flask import request,render_template,redirect,jsonify
from flask.helpers import url_for
from flask.wrappers import Request
import jinja2
import pymssql
import pandas as pd
from threading import Thread
from app2 import get_main_task, get_project_details, get_sub_task,get_proj_details

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
# print(proj) 
conn = pymssql.connect("10.20.4.44", "CSMSPMT_usr", "CSMSPMT_usr", "CSMSUAT")
query = f"SELECT Project_Id FROM VW_CSMS_PMT_ProjectDetails"
x = pd.read_sql(query,con=conn)['Project_Id'].tolist()

@app.route('/')
def lhome():
    proj = get_project_details(x[0:2],conn)
    return render_template('home copy 2.html',details=proj)

print(len(x))
@app.route('/result', methods=['GET'])
def result():

    offset = int(request.args['offset'])

    limit = int(request.args['limit'])
    if(offset+limit >=len(x)):
        print(x[offset:])
        details = get_project_details(x[offset:],conn)
    else:
        print('b')
        details = get_project_details(x[offset:offset+limit],conn)
    if(offset +limit <len(x)):
        next_url = '/result?limit='+ str(limit)+ '&offset='+str(offset+limit)
    else:
        next_url = ''
    prev_url = '/result?limit='+ str(limit)+ '&offset='+str(offset-limit)
    # return (jsonify({'result':details,'next_url':next_url,'prev_url':prev_url}))
    return render_template('newHome.html',details=details)
#pagination

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I don't see you adding onclick event on the button. `<button id='{{count}}' onclick="myFunction()">Expand</button>`

Comment: @charchit sorry my mistake I uploaded the wrong code

Comment: When debugging an issue like this, it helps to stand back, look at it, make a copy, then try to reduce it to a smaller bit of code that still exhibits the problem. Here, the problem has nothing do do with Flask (or the database), and everything to do JavaScript. As an exercise, try copying the template and replacing the tbody with a single, hard-coded line.